# How to fix inconsistent axis scales on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm saving a simple figure using the matplotlib, but I've noticed that the y-axis scale isn't consistent. Here's an example using an exaggerated data set of [100, 200, 300, 37290]

[Image of inconsistent scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK3ID.png)

I've tried both `matplotlib.plt.autoscale(False)` and `matplotlib.plt.autoscale(True)` but that doesn't seem to do anything. `matplotlib.plt.yscale("linear")` doesn't do anything either.

I've also noticed that it's constructing the y-axis scale using each and every datapoint.

[Image of crowded y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Js8.png)

Is there a way to have the y-axis look like the x-axis? (ie not use every single point in the data)

Comment: If you know your bounds when making your script you could use the `ax.set_ylim(min, max)` method. Is this the case? Or would it even be acceptable to say `my_max = max(dataset)`;`my_min=min(dataset)` and then plug these into the axis limits?

Comment: @Reedinationer `ax.set_ylim(min, max)` doesn't seem to affect the actual scale. [This is what it looks like](https://i.imgur.com/FzkjiE4.png)

Comment: Are you plotting with an `ax` or with `plt`? There are different methods for each. I'll try to make a post to elaborate

Comment: I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('chart.png')`

Comment: @Reedinationer I figured it out... I was plotting strings not ints. Thanks for taking the time to help though